# UICollectionView Delegate deallocated while performing reload

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a dashboard view controller pushed into UINavigationController, and dashboard view controller acts as a UICollectionView's delegate.

There is a back button on this dashboard view controller, so when user click back button, user can go back to the root view controller.

However, I have some code that will do a batch update for the UICollectionView, but when user click back button very fast before the block got executed, the dashboard view controller will be deallocated, so I got the crash.

The log indicates it breaks at `if (weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate)` because `weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate` is deallocated.
How do I avoid if the view controller is deallocated while another block tries to access it?

PS: disabling back button is NOT an option.

Log:

```
*** -[DashboardViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14ef57360
  * thread #1: tid = 0x1bb9b, 0x0000000184a72440 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 968, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x184a72440)
    frame #0: 0x0000000184a72440 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 968
    frame #1: 0x0000000184976b6c CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
  * frame #2: 0x000000010015b248 line 168: if (weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate && weakSelf.DashboardModel.chartArray.count > 0) {
```

code:
In my UICollectionView's reloadDashBoardData, weakSelf is a custom View container, it has the UICollectionView object:

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (weakSelf.ChartCollection) {
                if (weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate && weakSelf.DashboardModel.chartArray.count > 0) {
                    [weakSelf.ChartCollection performBatchUpdates:^{
                        [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
                            CLS_LOG(@"chart collection delegate:%@",weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate);
                            [weakself.ChartCollection reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[path]];
                        }];
                    } completion:nil];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you log `weakSelf` before  `if (weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate`?

Comment: I logged weakSelf, weakSelf.ChartCollection, they are a valid object. LLDB reports weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate is deallocated. if you try po weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate

Comment: that's weird because if the viewController is deallocated then weakSelf should be nil since it is a `weak`. However UICollectionView's delegate is assign and not weak which means it will not be nil is the viewController is deallocated ... you can try set the delegate with nil in the dealloc

Comment: no, weakSelf is not the VC, but another view container. delegate is the VC

Comment: OK everything is cleared now ... your  view container is not deallocated however the VC is deallocated you can set the delegate with nil in the dealloc or check why the view container is not deallocated in the first place

Comment: As you can see my code, the view container is still valid while in the callback block, then when user click back button at the same moment, VC got deallocated, but in the callback block, it tries to access the VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller dealloc, nil your collectionView delegates. I believe the issue is in the assign property of the CollectionView.

Comment: but inside a block, there should not be a strong self, should it?

Comment: You're taking a reference of the weakself not the self.

Comment: I am sorry if I mislead you, the reloadData is in my UIColelctionView .m file, and the problem is the delegate got deallocated. weakSelf is a custom view container, not the same object as delegate.

Comment: The problem is not in the delegate it's in the CollectionView itself. It's deallocated that's why you have to have a strong reference. Give it a try.

Comment: Not working... If you check my code, I already had a check for it:  ` if (weakSelf.ChartCollection) {
                if (weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate...` it passed if (weakSelf.ChartCollection), but throw exception at if (weakSelf.ChartCollection.delegate

Comment: If you check the delegate, it shows: @property(nonatomic, assign) id<UICollectionViewDelegate> delegate. So My understanding is even though the UICollectionView is still valid, the delegate can be deallocated, because it is 'assign' property

Comment: You're right. My bad. Can you separate the condition to allocate which part of the statement is causing the crash? To be fully sure?

Comment: I am looking for proper ways to do it. The pain point is I don't know when the delegate will be deallocated, how to testify if a object is deallocated, not nil? User can click back at any time, so while it is reloading data, and delegate got deallocated, even if (obj.delegate) will throw exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71652/discussion-between-ashraf-tawfeeq-and-wingzero).